# Time Series hourly data format

Tags: r, forecasting

From the data bellow I'm trying to create a time series object with zoo package

```
 head(data)                            MTU    Fossil
1 01.01.2015 00:00 - 01.01.2015 01:00 (CET)   2805
2 01.01.2015 01:00 - 01.01.2015 02:00 (CET)   2714
3 01.01.2015 02:00 - 01.01.2015 03:00 (CET)   2694
4 01.01.2015 03:00 - 01.01.2015 04:00 (CET)   2563
5 01.01.2015 04:00 - 01.01.2015 05:00 (CET)   2381
6 01.01.2015 05:00 - 01.01.2015 06:00 (CET)   2438
```

Comment: `dput(head(data))` pls

Comment: Still with dput(head(data)) I need to manually change the time format?

Comment: Do you need it as two columns ?

Comment: No, but still I need to know the exact time point

Comment: In the `MTU` it seems like a range for each row

Comment: It is a range,the data is in the above format, I just need to create a time series object.

Comment: The reason for the `dput` is that we have no idea what types the columns are

Comment: I will use the full hour as a starting point for time series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a time for the time series (depends on your application), could be the start, end or midpoint of the time range.

```
a$starttime=substr(a$MTU,1,16)
```

Write out a data frame with the correctly typed information

```
out = data.frame(times = strptime(a$starttime, format="%m.%d.%Y %H:%M", tz="CET"), Fossil=a$Fossil)
```

Convert to `ts` object or `zoo` object using your favorite method.